# Fading out in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want one of my textures to gradually fade out (make it more transparent) each frame. How I should do this?

I am using the fixed functionality pipeline.

Comment: Is it an homework that you want to finish with the minimum efforts?

Comment: you  have to use a fragment shader with an uniform variable for multiplying you final color. also blending should be enabled.